# mobaxterm use as vnc server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vnc

I'm running an application on an Ubuntu 22.04 server that uses GLX Standard (Paraview).
But the users don't have console rights and I have to implement a VNC server.
I see that MobaXterm supports different terminal types (xterm, xterm256,vt900) etc.
My question now is which VNC server do I need to install on Ubuntu Server, there are several (TightVNC, RealVNC etc.). Is there a recommendation?

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research. Here are a few suggestions on how to properly ask this type of question.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, VNC is a standard. If server or client support it any (almost) combination is fine.

Comment: @RomeoNinov , I know that.  It wasn't me who asked the question.  OP is the one that needs this information rather than being discouraged from posting questions.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, so the answer will be: Any. But will be too short to be accepted....